# sql show listbox values only when combobox is populated

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox, listbox

Firstly, I'm pretty new to access so I apologise if this is basic but I can't find the right answer either.

I've had some help setting this up so there are parts that have been created that I don't fully comprehend.

I have created a form that is to be used for data entry which consists of the following fields:

TEAMS - Combobox the rowsource of which is a table TEAMS; CALLREASONS - Multi-Select Listbox the records of which currently exist in a table CALLREASONS; ACTIONS - Multi-Select Listbox the records of which    currently exist in a table CALLACTIONS; SUBMIT - Button with VBA which    sends selected data to a number of tables.

The database works fine and things a saving where they should be and in the format they should be, the problem I'm having is with the display of the form.

I would like for the form to display blank when opened and after each time a record is submitted. However, if I set the rowsource of the listboxes to the tables all options show when the form is loaded and after each submission the options and the previous selections show.

How can I make it so that the first listbox CALLREASONS only displays possible options once a selection has been made in the combobox TEAMS and the second listbox CALLACTIONS only displays possible options once at least one selection is made in the listbox CALLREASONS ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the controls row sources on the Update or Enter events, or you can simply enable/disable them on the events.

Lets use 3 nested comboboxes for an example.

Combo1 Has rowsource set permanently as it is the top level.

Combo2 and Combo3 Have no rowsource set.

On the Enter event of Combo2, you can set the rowsource to

```
SELECT Pkey, DisplayText FROM tblOptions WHERE OptionGroupField = " & Forms!Form1!Combo1BoundField
```

On the Enter event of Combo3, you can set the rowsource to

```
SELECT Pkey, DisplayText FROM tblOptions WHERE OptionGroupField = " & Forms!Form1!Combo2BoundField
```

So on so forth.